# Should I use “each vehicle axle” or “each axle”?

Tags: grammar

Here are my constructions:

> 1. the car has mounted new brakes on each vehicle axle.
> 2. the car has mounted new brakes on each axle.

So my question is, should I use 'each vehicle axle' or 'each axle'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2) the car has mounted new brakes on each axle.

*each axle* is fine, as we know they are on the vehicle.  There is no point adding unneeded words that may cause a problem (Is it "vehicle" or "vehicle's"?).

But you wouldn't say "has mounted" in this context. This is saying the car mounted the brakes, which is not the case. You should say:

> the car has new brakes mounted on each axle.